# How to stop automatically call form tag on submit click event two times in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am submitting a form using react js submit() function but it's submitting multiple time. but not able to stop it. Below is my function :

```
const submitHandler = (event) =>{

 
    const expenseData = {
        title: enteredTitle,
        amount: enteredAmount,
        date: new Date(enteredDate)
    };

    console.log(expenseData);
};

return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className= 'new-expense__controls'>
            <div className= 'new-expense__control'>
                <label className= 'new-expense__control label' > Title </label>
                <input className= 'new-expense__control input' type='text' onChange={titleChangeHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className= 'new-expense__control'>
                <label className= 'new-expense__control label' > Amount </label>
                <input className= 'new-expense__control input' type='number' min='0.01' step='0.01' onChange={amountChangeHandler} />
            </div>
            <div className= 'new-expense__control'>
                <label className= 'new-expense__control label' > Date </label>
                <input className= 'new-expense__control input' type='date' min='2019-01-01' step='2023-12-31' onChange={dateChangeHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className='new-expense__actions'>
                <button > Add Expense </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In submitHandler function 1st line of function should be

"event.preventDefault();"

This will stop default behavior of the form & thus this function will be called only once, i.e., onSubmit={submitHandler}